# Issue with Personalization Feature in Car Rental Website

Tags: python, sql, angular, typescript

I'm currently working on a car rental website for a school project using Angular for the frontend and Python (Flask) for the backend. I'm facing challenges implementing a personalization feature where users should see reservations that belong to them and not someone else's when logged in.

Problem Description:
When a user logs in and navigates to the reservations page, the application should display only their reservations. However, I'm encountering difficulties with the user ID retrieval and data fetching process.

Code Overview:

I have two main components – frontend (Angular) and backend (Flask). I'm using SQLite for the database.

Backend Code:

User table and reservation table creation.
Registration, login, and reservation endpoints.
Storing user ID in the session after login.
Frontend Code:

Angular services for reservation and authorization.
Components for making reservations and displaying user reservations.
Reactive forms for login.

Backend:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, session
from flask_cors import CORS
import hashlib
import sqlite3

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

# Set the secret key
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret password'

def hash_password(password):
    return hashlib.sha256(password.encode()).hexdigest()

def create_users_table():
    with sqlite3.connect('rental-users.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                firstname TEXT NOT NULL,
                lastname TEXT NOT NULL,
                email TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                mobile TEXT NOT NULL,
                gender TEXT NOT NULL,
                hashed_password TEXT NOT NULL,
                reservations TEXT DEFAULT '[]' 
            )
        ''')
        conn.commit()

def create_reservations_table():
    with sqlite3.connect('rental-users.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reservations (
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                user_id INTEGER,
                brand TEXT NOT NULL,
                from_location TEXT NOT NULL,
                to_location TEXT NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)
            )
        ''')
        conn.commit()

create_users_table()
create_reservations_table()

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register_user():
    data = request.json

    # Validate required fields
    required_fields = ['firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'mobile', 'gender', 'pwd']

    for field in required_fields:
        if field not in data:
            return jsonify({'error': f'Missing required field: {field}'}), 400

    # Validate email uniqueness
    with sqlite3.connect('rental-users.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', (data['email'],))
        existing_user = cursor.fetchone()

    if existing_user:
        return jsonify({'error': 'Email is already registered'}), 400

    # Hash the password before storing it
    hashed_password = hash_password(data['pwd'])

    # Create a user object and add it to the users table
    with sqlite3.connect('rental-users.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, mobile, gender, hashed_password)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ''', (data['firstname'], data['lastname'], data['email'], data['mobile'], data['gender'], hashed_password))
        conn.commit()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Registration successful'})

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login_user():
    data = request.json

    # Validate required fields
    required_fields = ['email', 'pwd']
    for field in required_fields:
        if field not in data:
            return jsonify({'error': f'Missing required field: {field}'}), 400

    # Check if the user exists
    with sqlite3.connect('rental-users.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', (data['email'],))
        user = cursor.fetchone()

    if user:
        # Check if the provided password matches the hashed password in the database
        hashed_password = hash_password(data['pwd'])
        if hashed_password == user[6]:  # Assuming hashed_password is at index 6
            # Store user ID in session
            session['user_id'] = user[0]
            return jsonify({'message': 'Login successful'})
        else:
            return jsonify({'error': 'Invalid password'}), 401
    else:
        return jsonify({'error': 'User not found'}), 404

@app.route('/logout', methods=['POST'])
def logout_user():
    # Clear the user ID from the session
    session.pop('user_id', None)
    return jsonify({'message': 'Logout successful'})

@app.route('/make-reservation/<int:user_id>', methods=['POST'])
def make_reservation(user_id):
    data = request.json

    # Print the received data
    print('Received Data:', data)

    with sqlite3.connect('rental-users.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('''
            INSERT INTO reservations (user_id, brand, from_location, to_location)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
        ''', (user_id, data.get('brand'), data.get('from_location'), data.get('to_location')))
        conn.commit()

    return jsonify({'message': 'Reservation successful'})



@app.route('/user-reservations/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_user_reservations(user_id):
    with sqlite3.connect('rental-users.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE user_id = ?', (user_id,))
        reservations = [
            {'id': row[0], 'user_id': row[1], 'brand': row[2], 'from_location': row[3], 'to_location': row[4]}
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
    print(reservations)
    return jsonify(reservations)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

frontend:
AuthorizationService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthorizationService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';
  private user: any = { id: null, firstname: '', lastname: '', email: '' }; 
  private logged = false;
  private signedUp = false;

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.logged;
  }

  hasSignedUp(): boolean {
    return this.signedUp;
  }

  loginUser(loginData: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/login`;
    return this.http.post(url, loginData).pipe(
      tap((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        this.logged = true;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        this.logged = false;
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

  logout(): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/logout`;
    return this.http.post(url, {}).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.user = { id: null, firstname: '', lastname: '', email: '' }; 
        this.logged = false;
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      })
    );
  }

  registerUser(formData: any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/register`;
    return this.http.post(url, formData).pipe(
      tap((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        this.signedUp = true;
      }),
      catchError((error) => {
        this.signedUp = false;
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }

  getUserId(): number | null {
    return this.user.id ?? null;
  }

  constructor(private router: Router, private http: HttpClient) {}
}
```

ReservationService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ReservationService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  makeReservation(userId: number, selectedCar: string, fromLocation: string, toLocation: string): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/make-reservation/${userId}`;
    const reservationData = {
      brand: selectedCar,
      from_location: fromLocation,
      to_location: toLocation,
    };
    return this.http.post(url, reservationData);
  }

  getUserReservations(userId: number): Observable<any[]> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/user-reservations/${userId}`;
    return this.http.get<any[]>(url);
  }
  
}
```

MyReservationsComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthorizationService } from '../authorization.service';
import { ReservationService } from '../reservation.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { AvailableCarsService } from '../available-cars.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-reservations',
  templateUrl: './my-reservations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-reservations.component.css'],
})
export class MyReservationsComponent implements OnInit {
  reservationData = {
    brand:  '',
    from_location: '',
    to_location: '',
  };

  reservations: any[] = [];
  availableCars: any[] = [];
  

  constructor(
    private reservationService: ReservationService,
    private authService: AuthorizationService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
    private availableCarsService: AvailableCarsService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadReservationHistory();
    this.loadAvailableCars();
  }

  makeReservation() {
    const userId = this.authService.getUserId();

    console.log('Reservation Payload:', {
      userId: userId ?? 0,
      brand: this.reservationData.brand,
      from_location: this.reservationData.from_location,
      to_location: this.reservationData.to_location,
    });

    this.reservationService
      .makeReservation(
        userId ?? 0,
        this.reservationData.brand,
        this.reservationData.from_location,
        this.reservationData.to_location
      )
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.toastr.success('Reservation successful!', 'Success');
          this.loadReservationHistory();
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error(err);
          this.toastr.error('Error making reservation', 'Error');
        }
      );
  }

  loadReservationHistory() {
    const userId = this.authService.getUserId();

    this.reservationService.getUserReservations(userId ?? 0).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.reservations = res;
      },
      (err) => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

LoginComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthorizationService } from '../authorization.service';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
 constructor(private authService: AuthorizationService, private router: Router, private toastr: ToastrService) {}


  loginForm = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
    pwd: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6), Validators.maxLength(15)])
  });

  loginSubmitted() {
    this.authService.loginUser(this.loginForm.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      },
      err => {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }
  get Email(): FormControl {
    return this.loginForm.get('email') as FormControl;
  }

  get PWD(): FormControl {
    return this.loginForm.get('pwd') as FormControl;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  showToasterSuccess(){
    this.toastr.success("Logged in successfully !!", "Enjoy!!",{
    easing:"ease-in",
    easeTime: 1000
    });
  }

}
```

AppModule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbDropdownModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MyAvailableCarsComponent } from './my-available-cars/my-available-cars.component';
import { MyReservationsComponent } from './my-reservations/my-reservations.component';
import { AboutUsComponent } from './about-us/about-us.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { SignUpComponent } from './sign-up/sign-up.component';
import { CarInfoComponent } from './car-info/car-info.component';
import { ContactsComponent } from './contacts/contacts.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    MyAvailableCarsComponent,
    MyReservationsComponent,
    AboutUsComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignUpComponent,
    CarInfoComponent,
    ContactsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbDropdownModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'my-reservations', component: MyReservationsComponent},
      { path: 'my-available-cars', component: MyAvailableCarsComponent},
      { path: 'about-us', component: AboutUsComponent},
      { path: 'sign-up', component: SignUpComponent},
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      { path: 'contact', component: ContactsComponent},
      { path: '*', redirectTo:'/home' ,pathMatch : 'full'},
    ]),
    NgbModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      positionClass: "toast-top-right",
      preventDuplicates: true,
      timeOut: 2000,
    }),
    ToastModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

MyreservationsHtml

```
<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Make a Reservation</h2>
  <form (submit)="makeReservation()" #reservationForm="ngForm">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="brand" class="form-label">Car Brand</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="brand" [(ngModel)]="reservationData.brand" name="brand" required>
      </div>
      

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="from_location" class="form-label">From Location</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="from_location" [(ngModel)]="reservationData.from_location" name="from_location" required>
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="to_location" class="form-label">To Location</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="to_location" [(ngModel)]="reservationData.to_location" name="to_location" required>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Make Reservation</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>

  <div class="mt-5">
    <div class="text-center mb-4">
      <h2>Your Reservations</h2>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col">
      <div class="row row-cols-lg-4 row-cols-md-3 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-1" >
          <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
              <thead>
                  <tr class="table-info">
                      <th scope="col">#</th>
                      <th scope="col">Car</th>
                      <th scope="col">From</th>
                      <th scope="col">To</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  <tr *ngFor="let reservation of reservations; let i = index">
                      <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
                      <td>{{ reservation.brand }}</td>
                      <td>{{ reservation.from_location }}</td>
                      <td>{{ reservation.to_location }}</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table>
          <p *ngIf="reservations.length === 0">No reservations found.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: please share the result of the API `user-reservations` that is more that sufficient!, after that Front end or backend issue can be identified!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. the /user-reservations API endpoint returns the reservation history for all users instead of just the reservations associated with the logged-in user.                          Here's a sample of the data returned:  [
  {'id': 1, 'user_id': 0, 'brand': 'Mercedes', 'from_location': 'Kaduna', 'to_location': 'Abuja'},
  {'id': 2, 'user_id': 0, 'brand': 'BMW', 'from_location': 'Kaduna', 'to_location': 'Abuja'},
  {'id': 3, 'user_id': 0, 'brand': 'Mercedes', 'from_location': 'Kaduna', 'to_location': 'Abuja'},
]

Comment: Side note: Storing hashed passwords is about 3rd is the list of worst ways to implement password security (behind clear text and reversable encrypted passwords). It is susceptible to simple dictionary and rainbow table attacks. Being an apparent school exercise, it is good that at least some effort at password security was made, but in the future and in any live application, you should at least include *password salting* and perhaps *password peppering* in any password management scheme. Even better would be to use an off-the-shelf authentication package that already implements best practices.

Comment: *I am not a python/angular programmer, so this question might or might not make sense.* It appears that the logged in user information is stored in the `user` property of the `AuthorizationService` class. (1) Does the instance of that class (`authService` in `LoginComponent` and `MyReservationsComponent`) persist between UI actions? (2) Do `LoginComponent` and `MyReservationsComponent` share the same instance of `AuthorizationService`? If the answer is no for either question, the user information stored on login will not be visible later in the reservation logic.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try removing the tuple. It might solve your issue!

```
@app.route('/user-reservations/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_user_reservations(user_id):
    with sqlite3.connect('rental-users.db') as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE user_id = ?', user_id) # <-- CHANGED HERE
        reservations = [
            {'id': row[0], 'user_id': row[1], 'brand': row[2], 'from_location': row[3], 'to_location': row[4]}
            for row in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
    print(reservations)
    return jsonify(reservations)
```

Comment: Just tried it and it returned this error just shortened it because i wont be able to fit the rest  27.0.0.1 - - [27/Dec/2023 17:43:53] "GET /user-reservations/0 HTTP/1.1" 500 - ackages\flask\app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "C:\Users\E7490\PycharmProjects\PassaRentals\main.py", line 141, in get_user_reservations
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE user_id = ?', user_id) # <-- CHANGED HERE
ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type